# How to resend a failed Ajax request globally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a many Ajax request in my project and have a global Ajax Error Handler.

```
$( document ).ajaxError( function( event, jqxhr, settings) {

    if (// some condition) {
        // resend current Ajax Request
    }

});
```

How can I detect in which Ajax Request I catch an error and resend it ? I try to find "resend" solutions but do not find for global case. I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was even simpler than I expected:

```
$( document ).ajaxError( function( event, jqxhr, settings) {

    if (// some condition) {
        $.ajax(settings);
    }

});
```

The third parameter is a current Request